# How to change Google Cloud Platform Project's region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, region, zone

I'm trying to deploy [Google Cloud Datalab](https://datalab.cloud.google.com/) in one of my projects, but I'm receiving an error saying it can't deploy on a non-US located project. When creating the project I specified the European datacenters.

I cannot create a new project, because this one is benefiting from a promotional trial.

I have tried setting this metadata key-value pair in Compute, but it didn't help: `google-compute-default-region: us-east1`.

Error message in more detail (paraphrasing slightly):

```
The selected project is not enabled for App Engine, or it's location is unsupported.
Google Cloud Datalab uses Google App Engine and Managed VMs Beta which is U.S. only.
```

How can project's location be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running gcloud init, pick choice

```
[1] Re-initialize this configuration [default] with new settings
```

And then it'll eventually ask you to pick your region and zone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think project's location can be changed after creation. You need to create a new project in a new location.